# Check if process is running under the same user C#

Tags: c#, session, winapi, kernel32

I'm trying to check if a process is already running under the currently active session ID.

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
static extern bool ProcessIdToSessionId(uint dwProcessId, out uint pSessionId);
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
private static extern uint WTSGetActiveConsoleSessionId();


public static bool CheckCurrentuser()
    {
        uint sessionID;
        //get all process id's
        Process[] localByName = Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad");
        if (localByName.Length == 0)
        { return false; }
        else
        {           
        uint[] procarray = new uint[localByName.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < localByName.Length; i++)
            {
            procarray[i] = Convert.ToUInt32(localByName[i].Id);
            ProcessIdToSessionId(procarray[i], out sessionID);
            if (sessionID == WTSGetActiveConsoleSessionId())
                {
                return true;
                }
            }
        return false;
        }
    }
```

However, with the above code, I'm having some issues when testing with multi-user RDP sessions:

1. WTSGetActiveConsoleSessionId() seems to be returning 1 even tough this is not a truly "active" session.
2. ProcessIdToSessionId() is unconsistent, if the process is running under the user it returns the correct session id. When I test this under a different user it returns session ID 0 (services).

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: `WTSGetActiveConsoleSessionId`: [_"Retrieves the session identifier of the console session. The console session is the session that is currently attached to the physical console."_](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383835(v=vs.85).aspx). `ProcessIdToSessionId()`: [_"If the function fails, the return value is zero. To get extended error information, call GetLastError."_](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa382990(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: `ProcessIdToSessionId() is unconsistent` - this is not true. `ProcessIdToSessionId` correct return to you process session id. error in your code

Comment: in general you need have `SE_DEBUG_PRIVILEGE` for `ProcessIdToSessionId` or have `PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION` access to process. or you can enumerate all processes with names and *SessionId* by call `NtQuerySystemInformation` with *SystemProcessInformation* - for this you not need any privilege enabled and you got list of allprocesses at once

Comment: Running my test applicaiton as admin seemed to have solved the ProcessIdToSessionId issue. This will not be a problem, since i will be checking this in a service, thanks.

Is there an equivalent version of WTSGetActiveConsoleSessionId for all sessions?

Comment: `ProcessIdToSessionId issue` this is not api but your issue only. `ProcessIdToSessionId` need to open process with `PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION` for get it session id. only if you have `SE_DEBUG_PRIVILEGE` enabled in token this always ok. another way - enum process, for this not need priviledges

Comment: *Is there an equivalent version of WTSGetActiveConsoleSessionId for all sessions?* the question doesn't make sense; there is only one console session.  What do you actually want to know?  Whether or not the session is in use?

Comment: @HarryJohnston When you use a machine as an RDP 'server' WTSGetActiveConsoleSessionId will always show 1 since no physical user is connected to the console (eg behind the screen).

Comment: Yes, that's what it's supposed to do.  But what do you mean by "equivalent version for all sessions?"  What *specific* information are you trying to get?

Comment: I'm trying to retrieve the last active session (not only the last physical console session)